# Preventing page refresh from button in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I'm trying to display `GridView` on a `jquery` dialog. To bind data into `gridview`, i'm clicking button via `jquery` as below.

```
$('#' + '<%= btnBindGridViewData.ClientID %>').trigger("click");
```

But with this button click, page is refresh. so `jquery` dialog is disappearing.

**Button**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnBindGridViewData" OnClick="btnBindGridViewData_Click" Style="visibility: hidden;
    display: none;" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void btnBindGridViewData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind data into gridview from here
}
```

via jquery, click button as below.

```
$('#' + '<%= btnBindGridViewData.ClientID %>').trigger("click");
```

above code trigger `click` event of button and execute `btnBindGridViewData_Click()` and bind data into `gridview`.

Is there any way to prevent page refresh with button click and display `gridview` on `jquery` dialog ?

Comment: can you show click event?

Comment: @DKM  click event means ?

Comment: you are triggering `click()` on button, so have you written `click()` in javascript?

Comment: @DKM no. i don't need to write `click()` in javascript. I have a hidden Button on my page with id `btnBindGridViewData` and it has  `click` event as `OnClick="btnBindGridViewData_Click"`. in code behind, i'm binding data into `gridview` in `btnBindGridViewData_Click()` method. with `$('#' + '<%= btnBindGridViewData.ClientID %>').trigger("click");` button is clicking programmatically.

Comment: So, are you opening jQuery dialog from code behind?

Comment: @DKM no. i'm opening  jQuery dialog from client side. I'm using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my page. when user [click](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/) on day in `fullcalendar`, i'm opening dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved using `UpdatePanel`  as below.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnBindGridViewData" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
      //GridView here
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.

You have written logic of binding gridview in code behind file. In order for code behind file to execute, the page needs to refresh (post back)

You could stop the button from refreshing the page (`onclick = "return false;"`), but that would not execute your click event on server. You need to rethink your approach.

One way to run gridview on jQuery dialog is that you could set a hidden variable on page (to indicate that the button is clicked) and then in document ready you can open the jQuery dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // if flag == true, open dialog
});
```

Note: I won't recommend this approach though.

Comment: Achieved using `UpdatePanel`